# How can I turn my Raspberry Pi into a wireless receiver for a Microphone?

Tags: audio

My Raspberry PI is connected to a pair of speakers.

I can connect it to network without problems...

I would like to allow a user to speak into a microphone (when he pushes a record button) and hear the sound coming out from Raspberry's speakers.

The user has a windows pc and a classic, cheap microphone.

I would love to spend little or nothing to achieve the result...

Thanks!

Comment: You can basically follow this answer to a similar, yet different question:
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/using-pi-to-stream-all-audio-output-from-my-pc-to-my-stereo
Just make sure to change your Input device on the Windows PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, I would suggest using a voice client, such as mumble.

You set a mumble server (Mumble servers are also known as murmur) a machine, and then have clients on both the Windows machine with the Microphone, and the Pi with the speakers. As long as they are in the same channel on the server, the pi will play what ever it receives via mumble. The windows client can be configured with Push To Talk (PTT) or Voice Activation (VOX).

All the details can be found on the WIKI :- http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Main_Page