# Pi with PulseAudio over wifi - can't connect

Tags: wifi, audio, pulseaudio

I was trying to set up my RPi 1 as audio device for my laptop and found [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/11744). On the RPi all the steps worked fine, except that `/etc/default/pulseaudio` is empty. But in the linked answer the only reason to open that file is to check if pulse starts automatically, which it does anyway.

However, from my laptop, I can't connect to the Pi as it seems. I tried both the windows way (LineInCode) and on my Ubuntu 18.04 (using `paprefs`). I also have a Libreelec box running on my network, which gets picked up.

I can use `pactl list` on the RPi, which I think means that pulse is up and running.

The one line I don't get in the linked answer is

`load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.1.0/24`

Which I added to `/etc/pulse/system.pa`. My router IP is `192.168.1.254`, devices have IPs such as `192.168.1.181` and `192.168.1.65`. Maybe that could be a problem.

The RPi 1 is running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)`

I'm thankful for any suggestions on what to check/try.