# Raspi 4 - PulseAudio Server issues

Tags: networking, audio, pulseaudio, pi-4

I am currently trying to setup a pulseaudio server on a new Raspberry Pi 4.

In our office, we like to listen to music but passing the aux cord around is always a pain, so we thought we could use a Raspi 4 (with Raspbian Buster full) to setup a pulseaudio server so we could stream audio from pulseaudio on our laptops to the pi which is hooked up to the speakers.

I followed [this guide](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/using-pi-to-stream-all-audio-output-from-my-pc-to-my-stereo/) on how to set that up as well as [the arch wiki page on pulse audio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#PulseAudio_over_network) (and installed dbus-x11 which I found in another guide) but the Pi does not show up as an output device.

The Pi is fresh out of the box in case that makes a difference.

What could I be missing? Has something about this setup changed in the past years and that's the reason why it doesn't work anymore?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is `dbus-x11` for?

Comment: I am not quite sure. I just remember that guide saying one might need it if things don't work.