# Alternative to Bluetooth for streaming Audio via Raspberry to stereo

Tags: audio-playback

I stream audio via bluetooth to my Raspberry which is attached to my stereo.

Now, I'd like to have the same without bluetooth with IP only. (Basically to save the 5€ for a bluetooth dongle for a PC by investing hours in software configuration instead ;-)

But Wifi should have a higher bandwith than Bluetooth, so I think audio quality should be better.

Clients would be Windows and Android.

There is this old [thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/using-pi-to-stream-all-audio-output-from-my-pc-to-my-stereo) from seven years ago. Is ShairPort and Tuneblade still the way to go?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but... "ShairPort & Tuneblade"?? Why would you choose the lowest-voted of 9 answers? I can't recommend anything as I've not tried it myself, but [PulseAudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio) has been around for a while. Of course that's not always a "good thing", except that there may be a larger group to help if you get stuck. You may also wish to review the [ArchLinux wiki on PulseAudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio) as Arch has *very good* documentation. Good luck, and do let us know how you get on with this.

Comment: I did exactly that using an iOS device, and shairport-sync and a DAC device on an RPI2. I'd walk into the house, and use iTunes to cast to the RPI that was connected to an always on speaker and control the volume and music playlist from the phone itself. The github site is still maintained. https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync/

Answer (score 0):

Audio quality will be the same - as the network transfer is not the limiting factor. If you want better audio quality, you should invest in a DAC for your Pi as the standard audio output is known for poor quality. However, this is likely to cost many times more than a cheap Bluetooth dongle!

That aside, you can send audio from one Linux host to another Linux host over TCP/IP using pulseaudio. However, it seems you want to send from Android or Windows and pulseaudio is not well developed as a client on these platforms. If you are using Spotify as your source, you may find that you don't need to directly send audio from a Win or Android client and you can use Spotify Connect instead - https://github.com/librespot-org/librespot - which you can control on both Windows or Android.

I haven't been able to provide you with exactly what you need. You may find this guide gives you the inspiration you need to reach a solution that does what you want: https://mathieu-requillart.medium.com/my-ultimate-guide-to-the-raspberry-pi-audio-server-i-wanted-introduction-650020d135e1