# Raspberry PI as a WiFi external sound card

Tags: wifi, audio

The setup I am trying  to create is as follows:

1. Windows 10 laptop
2. Raspberry pi 2 (version with 1Gb RAM) with WiFi dongle and USB Sound Blaster sound card, where the microphone and headphones are connected
3. WiFi router

What I want to achieve:

1. Sound from Windows 10 laptop is forwarded via WiFi to Raspberry Pi and is played in headphones
2. Sound from Rapberry Pi microphone is sent from Raspberry Pi to Windows 10 for using in the apps that require microphone (saying, Zoom etc.)

So, the idea is to use Raspberry Pi as a WiFi sound card. Ideally if I could send sound from two laptops (both Win10) to Raspberry Pi - so I won't have to switch the sound card from one to another via USB, as it is done today.

Any idea how to make this possible? I tried to follow the instructions from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/using-pi-to-stream-all-audio-output-from-my-pc-to-my-stereo) , but it actually only forwarded sound from my onboard laptop mic to Raspberry Pi - which isn't smth I wanted to happen, and the speakers/headphones device from the laptop is not in the dev list, unfortunately.

Your support is appreciated.

Comment: You could try volumio - that can provide UPNP and Airplay playback - it may recognise the USB sound card omxplayer will let you use Chromecast for video and audio. Lots depends on what you are playing the music with as to if the Pi gets seen.  Sorry but no PC here to try as I use Airplay from tablets.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, will give it a try